# Compare strings in same column in [R]

Tags: r, string-matching

I have a data frame called 'messaround' in [r] which i have generated through creating phrases with ngrams on another dataframe called 'products'. I have a column in 'products' which have **both** the product type **and** additional info like quantity, size, colour, brand etc. I am looking to select the best cutoff point in 'messaround$phrases' which i can use as a pattern to extract out of my 'products' data frame and leave all the other info in place. I am looking to do this by marking messaround$selector with a '1' at the appropriate row (I can then filter messaround$phrases on this and take it forward from there quite happily (me thinks)). I just created messaround$selector initially as a vector of NAs.

messaround also has a column indicating the occurrence of each phrase. I am looking to keep the whole phrase where there is only one example of it. i.e. if I had 'car black' selector would be '1', however, if I had 'car black' and 'car blue' I would like the selector field for the row above both of these, which would be 'car' with an occurrence of two, to be '1' (using '1' is arbitrary and just for filtering at the next stage).

I hope my example below  with a small sample of my data better illustrates my task. I have marked selector with '1' at my ideal points.

From the outset I would like to apologise for not offering the solutions I have attempted to date. There have been a few but not worth showing you and would only confuse my question, I think. Thanks for any help in advance.

```
occurence   phrases                             selector
3           juice 250ml                         1
1           juice 250ml apple                   NA
1           juice 250ml apple malati            NA
1           juice 250ml apple malati 100%       NA
1           juice 250ml apple malati 100% x     NA
1           juice 250ml apple malati 100% x 1   NA
1           juice 250ml mango                   NA
1           juice 250ml mango malati            NA
1           juice 250ml mango malati 100%       NA
1           juice 250ml mango malati 100% x     NA
1           juice 250ml mango malati 100% x 1   NA
1           juice 250ml orange                  NA
1           juice 250ml orange malati           NA
1           juice 250ml orange malati 100%      NA
1           juice 250ml orange malati 100% x    NA
1           juice 250ml orange malati 100% x 1  NA
1           letaba                              NA
1           letaba herald                       NA
1           letaba herald newspaper             NA
1           letaba herald newspaper x           NA
1           letaba herald newspaper x 1         1
2           lettuce                             1
1           lettuce each                        NA
1           lettuce p/pack                      NA
1           lettuce p/pack x                    NA
1           lettuce p/pack x 1                  NA
```

Please note that I have just edited the 'lettuce' data as I had placed the selector '1' at the wrong row. Woops - sorry.

Comment: You question is not completely clear to me. If I understand correctly, the `products` `data.frame` is not relevant for the question. If so, I would remove this from the text. Why is 'letaba herald newspaper x 1' selected and not 'letaba herald'?

Comment: Hi Jan. I mentioned the _products_ _data.frame_ just to give context to what I am trying to achieve. I take your comment on relevance. I want 'letaba herald newspaper x 1' as the only occurrence of 'letaba herald' is also with 'x 1'. I need to id that whole pattern (in order to use the pattern to extract the entire string out of the 'products' dataframe).

Comment: If i compare it to 'juice 250ml' example, 'juice 250ml' occurs with three other trailing patterns, so I just need to id the common pattern (across the apple, mango and orange). 'Lettuce' also has two trailing patterns so I just need to id the 'lettuce' as the common pattern in that example. Does that make it clearer or have i just muddied the waters? I appreciate your time - thanks.

Comment: That makes it much clearer. Thanks. You should edit what you said above into your question. Unfortunately there is no obvious solution that springs to mind.